# Accessing element in multi-dimensional array, php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm currently developing a website in php. At the moment I am retrieving all data from a table in my database and returning it as an array called `'$divingTrips'`. It is returned in the following format using the            `print_r(array_values($divingTrips))` function :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
                         [DivingTripID] => 1 
                         [DivingTripName] => Newcastle Dive
                         [DivingTripLocation] => Newcastle   
                         [DivingTripDay] => Monday 
                         [DivingTripTime] => 12:06:57 ) 

       [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                         [DivingTripID] => 2
                         [DivingTripName] => Portrush Dive 
                         [DivingTripLocation] => Portrush 
                         [DivingTripDay] => Thursday 
                         [DivingTripTime] => 12:06:57 ) )
```

I am now trying to access single elements in the array in order to populate a drop-down menu and for other purposes. I am trying this to access the array:

```
echo  $divingTrips[0]['DivingTripID'];
```

I would have expected this to echo the value, '1', however, this is not working.. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Many Thanks.

Comment: `echo  $divingTrips[0]->DivingTripID;` This isn't a mult-dimensional array, it's an array of objects

Comment: Thank you Mark, that worked! Didn't realise it wasn't multi-dimensional. @MarkBaker

Comment: check your code, You are fetching object instead of array.. that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access stdClass as an array.
It is not an array, so you can't access it the same way.

In my opinion, you're trying to fetch rows from your database as php objects, but something in this process has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

echo  $divingTrips[0]['DivingTripID'];

Above statement will not work bcz $divingTrips array is storing items not as array, instead as objects.

Please verify the php code which is fetching array from DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$divingTrips = [];
$divingTrips[] = ["DivingTripID" => 1];

var_dump($divingTrips[0]["DivingTripID"]);
```

or

```
<?php

$divingTrips = [(object) ["DivingTripID" => 1]];

var_dump($divingTrips[0]->DivingTripID);
```